# How to get `nl` file from `pyomo` from inside `pyomo` script solver?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyomo

I am building many models using `pyomo`, and from what I understand, `pyomo` reformulates models before solving them.

I want to know exactly what the model looks like when it gets passed to the solver files `ipopt` and `couenne`.

From what I see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/XYeustbSj7o) it is not clear to me how to get the `nl` file from a script (but I see how to get it from the command line).

Here is how I am solving the models in pyomo:

```
ipopt_solver = SolverFactory('ipopt')
ipopt_results_solver = ipopt_solver.solve(my_model, tee=True)
print ipopt_results_solver

couenne_solver = SolverFactory('couenne')
couenne_results_solver = couenne_solver.solve(my_model, tee=True)
print couenne_results_solver
```

How do I get the `nl` file just before solving? (and I assume it is just as easy to spit out another format other than `nl`).

Answer (score 4):

If you just want the NL file, you can call the `write` method on the model with a filename that ends with `.nl` (e.g., `my_model.write('junk.nl')`.

If you want to tell the solver object to not delete the temporary solver files so that you can access them after the solve, you should add `keepfiles=True` to the solve call. This will print the location of the temporary solver files. If you need to access them from the script, I believe the NL filename can be found as one of the entries in the `_problem_files` list attribute on the solver object. The log filename is stored on the `_log_file` attribute.